# ALTER TABLE constraint problem

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, constraints

I'm trying to run the following SQL statement:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('MyTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE MyTable

SELECT
    a.UserId
INTO
    MyTable
FROM
    UsersTable a
WHERE
    a.UserId='12359670-1DC9-4A0A-8AE5-29B664C1A57E'


ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD PRIMARY KEY(UserId)
```

However, I get the following error:
*Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'MyTable'.*

Any ideas?

Comment: What flavour of RDBMS are you using?  How are you running these statements?  What feedback do you get?  Especially from the third statement - that is, does the `ALTER TABLE ... NOT NULL` statement run without error?

Comment: Yep, I rushed a little bit with the question. I'm using MS SQL server. I get the error from the last line. I'm running this statements from within a stored procedure. Is it possible that the "NOT NULL" does not apply before the last line is running?

Comment: @LiorO: correct, SQL Server doesn't run line by line as such. See my answer please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes SQL Server based on `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`

Put a GO between (or relevant batch separator if not SQL Server)

```
....
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
GO
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD PRIMARY KEY(UserId)
```

At batch compile time, the column is nullable. So break up the batches.

SQL isn't a line by line procedural language

You'll have to do this in a stored procedure

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
EXEC('ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD PRIMARY KEY(UserId)')
```

Comment: gbn, thanks for the reply. Actually I already tried this but I have another problem when doing so. The statement above runs from within "ALTER PROCEDURE", when I add the GO, the "ALTER PROCEDURE" fails to run due to incorrect syntax (when I add the GO and run the statement not from within the alter procedure it works fine). So...I'm glad you directed me to the root cause. I'll start looking for other solutions (other the GO) in this direction. 10x

Comment: OK, just read what 'GO' does and I understand why my ALTER PROCEDURE fails. I have some variables declared before the GO but they are not recognized after it.

Comment: :-) Just updated with similar solution...10x...I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.
I'm using the following statement:

```
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL N'ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL'
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL N'ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD PRIMARY KEY(UserId)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need dynamic SQL. Just create the table and the key first.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO MyTable (UserId)
SELECT UserId
FROM UsersTable
WHERE UserId='12359670-1DC9-4A0A-8AE5-29B664C1A57E';
```